# Two backgrounds horizontal in div one rounded div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have small problem with make a two horizontal backgrounds in one div with border radius. I want the main div was a circle.

My code

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
.split-outer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #014495;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
  .split-outer::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
  }

.split-inner{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

span{
    display: block;
}

  span.split-title{
    padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 55px;
}

  span.split-content{
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size:18px;
    color: #014495;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fliud">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="split-outer">
            <div class="split-inner">
                <span class="split-title">100</span>
                <span class="split-content">Lorem ipsum</span>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But i have a small bug, in the after element i see some blue backround line from the first div. It looks like a border line genrated from the radius. But i wannt a clean white round background.

Codepen prev :http://codepen.io/michal_t/pen/KdoZYz/

Comment: Why don't you use a background image instead?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Ararat/pen/wKmyzK?editors=110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the top half of the background by removing the background color from `.split-outer` and then using a :before pseudo, similar to how the bottom half is created with an :after pseudo.

```
.split-outer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #014495;
  background-image: initial;
  background-position-x: initial;
  background-position-y: initial;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat-x: initial;
  background-repeat-y: initial;
  background-attachment: initial;
  background-origin: initial;
  background-clip: initial;
  background-color: #014495;
  border-top-right-radius: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYmdva

Answer (score 1):

Put `border: 2px solid white` in `:after`.

Here is css code:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
.split-outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #014495;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.split-outer::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.split-inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    display: block;
}
span.split-title {
    padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 55px;
}
span.split-content {
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #014495;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnsank6u/3/).